# PHP & Oracle Auto Input Value

Tags: php, oracle

I have a `select` dropdown box that takes its values from a `Products` table. This dropdown box passes the `Product_ID` of the chosen product to an `insert` SQL statement. Each of these products have a price (same column as the `product_id` in the products table).

How do I get the price of the chosen product in a live sort of manner (or I think dynamically is the right word here) so that I can automatically calculate the total amount? Aside from the price, I have a textbox for quantity and total square feet, these two are for manual input by the user. The last box (Total Amount) is where I want the automatically computed value to appear.

Any help that could get me started would be appreciated thanks!

Can't post images yet so I'm sorry can't provide a visual .__.

Edit: I have a semi-working jquery, I now only need to get the Price of the chosen Product so that I can put it in a var price.

Editedit: Added whole code.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['LoginStatus'] == false)
    header('location: ../index.php');

if(isset($_POST['logout']))
{
    $_SESSION['LoginStatus'] = false;
    header('location: ../index.php');
}

$conn = oci_connect("dbase", "dbase", "localhost/XE");
$query = "SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME FROM customers order by customer_id";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID";
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID";
$statement = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$statement2 = oci_parse($conn, $query2);
$statement3 = oci_parse($conn, $query3);

?>
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Add New Order Record</title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/stickyfooter.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(#inp).keyup(function(){
                var inpvalue= $('#inp').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',  
                    data: ({p : inpval}),
                    url: 'getprice.php',
                    success: function(data){
                         $('.results').html(data); 
                    });
                });

        });
    </script>
</head>  
<body>  
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Top-C Graphics</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav><br><br><br>
    <form action="addneworder2.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">
        <table style="width: 500px" align="center" class="table table-hover">
            <div align="center"><h5>Order</h5></div>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer*</th> 
                <td>
                    <select name="CustomerID" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <?php

                            if(oci_execute($statement)){
                                while(ocifetchinto($statement, $row, OCI_ASSOC)){
                                    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n", htmlentities($row['CUSTOMER_ID']), 
                                                                                htmlentities($row['CUSTOMER_ID'].' '.$row['CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME'].' '.$row['CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME']));
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Type*</th> 
                <td>
                    <select name="ProductID" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <?php

                            if(oci_execute($statement2)){
                                while(ocifetchinto($statement2, $row, OCI_ASSOC)){
                                    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n", htmlentities($row['PRODUCT_ID']), 
                                                                                htmlentities($row['PRODUCT_NAME'].' '.$row['PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION']));
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Date* </th> 
                <td><input type="date" name="OrderDate" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Delivery Date* </th> 
                <td><input type="date" name="DeliveryDate" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Description* </th>   
                <td><textarea name="OrderDescription" required rows="5" cols="60" maxlength="500" placeholder="Enter description here."></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>Total Square Feet* </th> 
                <td><input type="text" name="TotalSF" id="TotalSF" required></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>Quantity* </th> 
                <td><input type="text" name="QtyPurchased" id="QtyPurchased" required></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>Total Amount* </th> 
                <td><span class="amount" id="TotalAmount"></span></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>Assigned Worker* </th> 
                <td>
                    <select name="Worker" required>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <?php

                            if(oci_execute($statement3)){
                                while(ocifetchinto($statement3, $row, OCI_ASSOC)){
                                    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n", htmlentities($row['EMPLOYEE_ID']), 
                                                                                htmlentities($row['EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME'].' '.$row['EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME']));
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr><td><b>*<font color="red">required fields</font></b></td></tr>
        </table>
        <div class="results">

        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Record" onclick="return confirm('Add new order?')">
            <input type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>  
</html> 
<script>    
var price = 0;
var quantity = 0;
var totalsf = 0;

$("#QtyPurchased").change( function(){
    quantity = $("#QtyPurchased").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#TotalSF").change( function() {
    totalsf = $("#TotalSF").val();
    calcTotals();
});

function calcTotals(){
    $("#TotalAmount").text(quantity * totalsf);
}
</script>
```

Php file which does the inserting

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['LoginStatus'] == false)
    header('location: ../index.php');

if(isset($_POST['logout']))
{
    $_SESSION['LoginStatus'] = false;
    header('location: ../index.php');
}
?>

<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Add New Order Record</title>  
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/stickyfooter.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>  
<body>  
    <?php  
        $objConnect = oci_connect("dbase","dbase","localhost/XE");
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE Order_Number = (SELECT MAX(ORDER_NUMBER)+1 FROM ORDERS)";
        $strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENTS WHERE Invoice_Number = '".$_POST['InvoiceNumber']."' ";
        $strSQL3 = "SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = '".$_POST['ProductID']."' ";

        $objParse2 = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL2);
        oci_execute($objParse2, OCI_DEFAULT);
        $objResult2 = oci_fetch_array($objParse2);

        $objParse3 = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL3);  
        oci_execute($objParse3,OCI_DEFAULT);
        $objResult3 = oci_fetch_array($objParse3,OCI_BOTH);
        $price = $objResult3["PRICE"];

        $objParse = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL);  
        oci_execute($objParse,OCI_DEFAULT);  
        $objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse);  
        if($objResult){  
            echo "Order Number already exists. Try again.";
            echo "<br><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'>";
            echo "<br><a href='../orders.php'>Go back to Orders table.</a>";
        }
        else if($objResult2){
            echo "Invoice Number already exists. Try again.";
            echo "<br><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'>";
            echo "<br><a href='../orders.php'>Go back to Orders table.</a>";
        }
        else{
            $qty = $_POST["QtyPurchased"];
            $dimensions = $_POST["TotalSF"];

            $TotalAmount = $qty * $dimensions * $price;

            $strSQL = "";
            $strSQL = "INSERT ALL ";
            $strSQL .="INTO ORDERS ";
            $strSQL .="(Order_Number, Customer_ID, Order_Description, Order_Date, Delivery_Date, Total_Amount) ";  
            $strSQL .="VALUES ";  
            $strSQL .="(orders_seq.nextval,'".$_POST["CustomerID"]."','".$_POST["OrderDescription"]."','".$_POST["OrderDate"]."','".$_POST["DeliveryDate"]."' ";
            $strSQL .=",'".$TotalAmount."') ";
            $strSQL .="INTO PAYMENTS ";
            $strSQL .="(Order_Number, Invoice_Number, Date_Issued, Amount_Paid, Issued_By) ";
            $strSQL .="VALUES ";
            $strSQL .="(orders_seq.currval,'".$_POST["InvoiceNumber"]."','".$_POST["DateIssued"]."','".$_POST["InitialDeposit"]."','".$_POST["IssuedBy"]."') ";
            $strSQL .="INTO LABOR ";
            $strSQL .="(Employee_ID, Labor_Number, Date_Started, Date_Finished) ";
            $strSQL .="VALUES ";
            $strSQL .="('".$_POST["Worker"]."',labor_seq.nextval,null,null) ";
            $strSQL .="INTO ORDERLINE ";
            $strSQL .="(Labor_Number, Qty_Purchased, Product_ID, Order_Number) ";
            $strSQL .="VALUES ";
            $strSQL .="(labor_seq.currval,'".$_POST["QtyPurchased"]."','".$_POST["ProductID"]."',orders_seq.currval) ";
            $strSQL .="SELECT * from DUAL";

            $objParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);  
            $objExecute = oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);
            if($objExecute){  
                oci_commit($objConnect); //*** Commit Transaction ***//  
                echo "Save completed.";
                echo "<br><a href='../orders.php'>Go back to Orders table.</a>";
            }  
            else{  
                oci_rollback($objConnect); //*** RollBack Transaction ***//  
                $e = oci_error($objParse);  
                echo "Error Save [".$e['message']."]";  
                echo "<br><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'>";
            }  
        }  
        oci_close($objConnect);  
    ?>
</body>  
</html>
```

`getprice.php`

```
<?php
$objConnect = oci_connect("dbase","dbase","localhost/XE");

$id=$_POST['p'];
$strSQL = "SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE Product_ID = '".$id."' ";

while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($strSQL)){
    $row['PRICE'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share whole source

Comment: Hi, I added the whole source. But should I also add the php file which does the insert into oracle?

Comment: you should then you will get faster responses.

Comment: Added the php file for inserting...

Answer (score 0):

> Refer this for: How do I get the price of the chosen product in a live sort of manner (or I think dynamically is the right word here) so that I can automatically calculate the total amount?

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1283&lngWId=5

> For Last Query:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/rdb/automatic-columns-132042.pdf